# Elixir Phoenix Web Framework Ajax upload image

Tags: phoenix-framework

I'm quite new with Elixir Phoenix framework, so I need a sample code of Ajax Image Uploader in Phoenix, I don't know how to start. 
I try to follow this link http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/file-uploads , but it doesn't work :(

Comment: The link shows receiving file temporary, so you should store receiving file to a file or s3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Someone wrote a package for handling images once you upload them.

https://github.com/stavro/arc_ecto and https://github.com/stavro/arc

Comment: Author of `arc` here... Thanks! :)

Comment: @SeanS Thanks for arc! :)